# C dynamically growing array realloc issue

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, realloc

I want to implement *dynamically growing array* in C.
I read the words from a file to a *char*** array and when the array is full grow its size by 2. But when I reallocate the memory, the first two elements of the array is lost. I tried with lines = realloc() but it's crashing. What am I doing wrong?

test.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9 (no end of line)
```

my output:

```
─
đ%
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test9
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int size = 8;

char **read(FILE *input, char **lines, int *lSize) {
    for (int i = 0; !feof(input); i++) {
        *lSize += 1;

        if (*lSize > size) {
            realloc(lines, (size *= 2) * sizeof(char *));
            for (int j = (*lSize) - 1; j < size; j++) {
                lines[j] = (char *) malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
            }
        }

        fscanf(input, "%s", lines[i]);
    }

    return lines;
}

int main(){
    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    char **lines = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        lines[i] = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    }

    int lsize = 0;

    read(file, lines, &lsize);

    printf("lSize:%d\n", lsize);
    printf("size:%d\n", size);

    for (int i = 0; i < lsize; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        free(lines[i]);
    }

    free(lines);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: realloc returns a pointer, which you must reassign to lines.  `lines = realloc(lines, (size *= 2) * sizeof(char *));` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Comment: yeah I tried that, and it didn't work

Comment: So you also need to do `lines = read(file, lines, &lsize);`

Comment: And your use of `feof()` is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: ```lines = read(file, lines, &lsize);``` with ```lines = realloc(...)```  solved it!

Answer (score 0):

given `char **read(FILE *input, char **lines, int *lSize)`

what does: `realloc(lines, (size *= 2) * sizeof(char *))` do?

Well it changes the sizes of the memory block pointed to by `lines`, possibly by moving it.
That is why it returns a new pointer. Just assigning that new pointer back to `lines` won't help much (on its own) as that only updates the local variable `lines` in this function.

But luckily `lines` is also returned from the function. But its return value is ignored in main so after `read` returns, the `lines` in main may be a bogus pointer.
do `lines = read(file, lines, &lsize)` in main as well.